# What's the difference between the container and html_tag render elements?

Tags: 8, theming

What is the difference between render elements of #type html_tag (set to div) and container in Drupal 8?

Is the container render element, a simpler version of html_tag? Easier for processing to preprocess container elements?

I note that:

- historically, [html_tag was for void elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2981632) in the  tag in Drupal 7.x.
- if the container element is used a form, it [adds the form-wrapper/js-form-wrapper class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21container.html.twig/8.8.x) and [an HTML ID if it has #array_parents](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_container/8.8.x).

Perhaps my theories are correct (easier to leave be for historical reason / form element reasons)?

PHP:

```
  use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;

  $variables['myhtml_tag'] = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'div',
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => 'my-container-class1',
    ],
    'child' => [
      '#markup' => new TranslatableMarkup('Some Container text1.'),
    ],
  ];

  $variables['mycontainer'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => 'my-container-class2',
    ],
    'child' => [
      '#markup' => new TranslatableMarkup('Some Container text2.'),
    ],
  ];
```

HTML:

```
<div class="my-container-class1">Some Container text1.</div>

<div class="my-container-class2">Some Container text2.</div>
```

Comment: `Is the container render element, a simpler version of html_tag?` Iooks like it, also to save having to type the `'#tag' => 'div',` part. A dedicated container #type was probably created since it's something used often and makes it easier to use and identify.

Comment: Likely yeah, was there a Change Record for the `container` element ?

Comment: I started with D7, but reading this [kiamlaluno's comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-should-i-handle-container-form-elements#comment473_533), and the fact that he [asked when they should be used](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/381/when-should-the-container-form-element-be-used) sounds like they didn't exist in D6 and were introduced in D7 and there were no change record/docs about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did ["Blame" on the 7.x system.module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blame/7.x/modules/system/system.module) after I didn't found a clue of `'container'` in the 6.x branch. In the "Blame" you can see that Dries himself committed the patch that introduced `$types['container']` in 2010 and that it leads back to the following issue on drupal.org:

- [#557272: FAPI: JavaScript States system](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/557272)

The issue which introduced `#states` to the **Form API**! Now let's scan the page for "container". Okay, [comment #36](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/557272#comment-2117852) explains quite a bit of the reason why it was introduced:

> As discussed with kkaefer and tha_sun, we switched the "wrapper" Form
> API element type to "container" to not get too confused with other
> "wrapper" stuff, like "wrapper_callback", "theme_wrappers", etc. The
> "container" type still uses the CSS class of "*-wrapper" though, to
> match with the rest of the Drupal coding standards.

And in the [commit](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/commit/045074d4c51025a7c1561a9bf2e2a8b05441b23d) itself you then can see how `container` elements already replace some `markup` elements (`markup` being the default if `#type` omitted) which had `'#prefix' => '<div>', '#suffix' => '</div>` with hardcoded HTML.

To make it short: Container is a classical wrapper. And more of a **form element**. Whereas `html_tag` is more of a **render element**, traditionally used for void elements, often in the HTML `<head>`. Like placing meta tags or placing JavaScript and CSS libraries in script tags.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. The way I see it, the container is a simple way to wrap things in a `<div>`. This is useful to add structure to forms, but also very useful for other situations where you need to build larger render arrays. I often use it like this (simplified example) because it makes your code clearer:

```php
$build['wrapper'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => ['class' => ['select-wrapper']],
];

$build['wrapper']['select'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select'),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#empty_option' => $this->t('- Select an option -'),
];
```

Also, the fact that a container doesn't require additional settings makes it suitable for and often used in the #theme_wrappers property like this:

```php
$form['description'] = [
  '#markup' => $description,
  '#theme_wrappers' => ['container'],
];
```

Personally, I only use the html_tag type for simple elements other than a div, for instance:

```php
$build['heading'] = [
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'h2',
  '#value' => 'My Title',
];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The container element makes most sense in a form. It can be arranged in groups, it can be made optional and the ID, if missing, is auto-generated.